# RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes causes UI to hang

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I can successfully register my app for push notifications:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(
    UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert
    | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge
    | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound);
```

But whenever I execute this, my UI hangs for usually 2-3 seconds.  Even if I have it early in the app lifecycle as recommended (e.g., even `WillFinishLaunching`) my UI still hangs once my first ViewController loads.

My first thought was to execute the registration in a separate thread, but MonoTouch prevents this:

```
// From MonoTouch.UIKit
public virtual void RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationType types)
{
    UIApplication.EnsureUIThread();
```

My next thought was to at least pop up a `UIAlertView` box to let the user know something's going on, but for some reason it didn't display until *after* the registration took place, resulting in the `UIAlertView` opening and immediately closing!

```
modalPopup = new UIAlertView("Working", "The application is loading...", null, null);
modalPopup.Show();
// It doesn't show here!
RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes();
// It shows here!
modalPopup.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, true);
```

How can I either

1. Stop the push notification registration from tying up my UI thread
2. cover up the UI freeze?

Comment: I noticed that receiving a token kills any pending async calls !

Answer (score 1):

Did you override public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)

or

public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)

I've had similar problem where within Registered... function, I called a web service to upload the device token. But the web call wasn't within another thread so it caused to freezes UI.